# Учет заявок. Как хранить несколько исполнителей для каждого этапа заявки?

Tags: sql-server, проектирование

Есть следующая схема бд:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где:

- Requests - Заявки;
- RequestHistories - история *жизни* заявки;
- RequestStates - справочник состояний заявки(*Открыта*,*В работе*,*Закрыта* и т.п.);
- RequestTypes - справочник типов заявки(*Аварийная*, *Плановая*, и т.п);

Необходимо добавить возможность указать исполнителей для *этапа* заявки, т.е. для каждой записи в таблице `RequestHistories` может быть любое кол-во *исполнителей*.

Таблица `Performers` планируется что будет выглядеть например как то так:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.NewPerformers (
  Id INT IDENTITY,
  Surname NVARCHAR(100) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
  Name NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
  Patronymic NVARCHAR(50) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NOT NULL,
  UnitId INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.NewPerformers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id),
  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.NewPerformers_dbo.Units_UnitId] FOREIGN KEY (UnitId) REFERENCES dbo.Units (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Мне приходит на ум несколько вариантов: в таблицу `RequestHistory` добавить поле типа `varchar` в котором хранить `Id` исполнителей через разделитель, или же можно создать отдельную таблицу `RequestHistoryPerformers`:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.RequestHistoryPerformers (
  Id INT IDENTITY,
  RequestHistoryId INT NOT NULL,
  PerformerId INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.RequestHistoryPerformers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id),
  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.RequestHistoryPerformers_dbo.Performers_PerformerId] FOREIGN KEY (PerformerId) REFERENCES dbo.Performers (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT FK_RequestHistoryPerformers_RequestHistories_Id FOREIGN KEY (RequestHistoryId) REFERENCES dbo.RequestHistories (Id)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Собственно вопрос как *лучше/правильней* организовать хранение исполнителей для *этапа* заявки?

Comment: Создать отдельную таблицу.

Comment: "добавить поле типа varchar в котором хранить Id исполнителей через разделитель". Нормализация? Не, не слышал =) создайте таблицу исполнителей и связь многие ко многим

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик слышал, если бы не слышал то наверно второго варианта не было

Comment: Ну вопрос тогда собственно сам себя решает. Вам бы не знать, что хранить идешники в строке это не вариант.

Comment: Ну конечно отдельную таблицу, только прикиньте, нужен ли в ней `Id`, или достаточно будет составного первичного ключа `(RequestHistoryId, PerformerId)`, который вдобавок обеспечит уникальность пары, чего, кстати, сейчас у вас нет.

Comment: @i-one спасибо, да что то я не подумал про одного исполнителя несколько раз

Comment: А пусть он типа работает за двух

Comment: @Sergey ну в `gui` не возможно выбрать одного исполнителя несколько раз, но и ограничение на стороне бд я все таки сделаю, так сказать на всякий случай ;)

Comment: Не знаю насколько актуально уже, но все-таки. У нас была подобная схема (даже такая же) на работе, только в другой предметной области. В терминах вашей: получалось, что все возможные этапы хранились в отдельной таблице; для заявки была таблица для связи с этапом, типо DefiniteRequestStep; и для каждого такого конкретного этапа была таблица связи с пользователем. Но у нас еще у этапа было состояние свое, там "начат, ожидает, выполнен".